# JS/DOM optimization: using :after content styling instead of altering innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, optimization

Basically, given that all possible contents of an element are known in advance, you can use a bunch of :after content styles instead of altering the innerHTML of the element. Just change the class to get new content.

My profiling in Chrome indicates that this does improve performance a bit, but I'm not entirely sure, as the cost might then be hidden somewhere else? And I'm not sure if it's a bad idea for other browsers besides Chrome. Any thoughts on this?

Please note that the context here is for 60 frames per second simulations/visualisations, so in this context 2 vs 4 milliseconds is a big and significant difference, which it might not be in the context of a page load.

Example styles for numbering can be seen here: https://github.com/magwo/elevatorsaga/blob/2fa5dc0c0397d0565ce5dcc45c68b19d924a4955/style.css#L290

Comment: I'm also interested to know.

Answer (score 0):

`pseudo-elements` are `design elements` they are not content, they don't appear in the source code, they don't exist in the `DOM`, they wont be crawled by search engines, you cannot select or copy them, and of course, they don't exist without `CSS`, which is a `style-sheet`.

It may be faster, but that is probably because it is not content. And maybe it is easier for the browser to change a class than change the content of an element.

The question is, do you want to change the content, or the visual representation of it?

As for the implementation, I believe that having every possible content loaded in to a `CSS` is not an optimization, the same thing applies if you are planning to request a new CSS file for every new content change.

Finally, at least for now, you can't style individual parts of the content of a `pseudo-element`, you can't add paragraphs,spans and other markup.